# tensorflow slim batchnorm layer no update ops created

Tags: tensorflow

I was trying to use `slim.batch_norm` layer, I'm sure I set the is_training to be true, but after batchnorm layer is constructed, `tf.get_collections(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)` returns empty list, really confused, since there is documentation in `slim.batch_norm`:

```
  Note: when training, the moving_mean and moving_variance need to be updated.
  By default the update ops are placed in `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS`
```

can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

When you create the optimizer you should do it the following way:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(SOME_LEARNING_RATE)
gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss=loss, var_list=variables)
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
     train_step = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=gradients)
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are placing `tf.get_collections(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)` before you perform batch_norm. So end up with nothing to be updated.